# why is my date validator not working?

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

I'm trying to validate a date entered into text boxes like so using a custom validator:

```
string CombinedDate = String.Format("{0}-{1}-{2}", txtDay.Text, txtMonth.Text, txtYear.Text);

if (DateTime.TryParseExact(CombinedDate, "dd-MM-YYYY", DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo, DateTimeStyles.None, out date))
{
    args.IsValid = true;
}
else
{
    args.IsValid = false;
}
```

but it fails for 21-02-2005 why is that?
and how can i fix it

Comment: What other dates does it fail for ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

YYYY must be yyyy

See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx) for other formats from MSDN